# android: how do i sign my app using an existing key?

Tags: android, code-signing

My company is attempting to publish its first Android app on the market, and we have gotten to the code signing step. We have keys that we use for our other products and use the windows codesign tools to sign our products. We would like to use the same key to sign the Android app, but (obviously) cannot use the windows signing tool (because it only signs .dll's and .exe's)

Does anyone know how to sign an android app using existing keys? (.spc and .pvk files)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [converting the PVK into something for the Java keystore](http://www.entropy.ch/blog/Developer/2007/08/16/Converting-Microsoft-pvk-Private-Keys-to-Java-Keystore.html). The odds of the resulting key being something the Android Market will accept is low -- for example, the Android Market requires the key to be good for at least 25 years, that you will use the same key for the entire lifetime of your app, etc.

Since the Android key can be self-signed, you are not saving any money this way and are only wasting time and increasing risk, IMHO.

Comment: Yea, thats what we figured. It turned out that our key wasnt good for 25 years, so it was moot-point. thanks for the input!